# Vue.js application with prop type [String,Number]. Yet getting error: Expected string, got number. Why?

Tags: vue.js, types, vue-props

I have a vue.js application, and I want to set the type on one of my props to both String and Number:

```
props: {
  id: {
    default: null,
    type: [ String, Number ]
  }
}
```

I do this because the id I want sometimes comes in the form of a string, sometimes a number.

But I'm still getting this error in the browser console:

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "id". Expected String with value "9539020", got Number with value 9539020.
```

Why is it expecting ONLY a string when I specified the type as string or number? Is my syntax wrong?

Thanks

Comment: How are you calling the prop?

Comment: Check as the docs says: `props: { id: [String, Number] }`.

Comment: Your syntax is 100% correct `props` object-based syntax (via [Vue API](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#props)), so that's not your issue. Echoing Hias, show us how you call your component and pass your prop.

Comment: Nothing fancy, just doing this: ```<component :id="id" />```

Comment: please share the whole code

Comment: I'm not getting any repro... [Here's a fiddle](https://jsbin.com/zinupimeru/1/edit?html,js,console,output) I threw together.